# Show buttons inside SearchView on onMenuItemActionExpand

Tags: android, xml, menu, android-actionbar, searchview

I have SearchView on toolbar and i want add time button inside SearchView when expand and hide when collapse.

[image]

**onCreateOptionsMenu**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.nearby_friends_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_PTL);

    searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
    searchView.setIconified(true);

    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
    Button timeButton = new Button(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams navButtonsParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(toolbar.getHeight() * 2 / 3, toolbar.getHeight() * 2 / 3);
    // LinearLayout.LayoutParams navButtonsParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    timeButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp));
    ((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0)).addView(timeButton, navButtonsParams);
    ((LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    searchView.setQueryHint("Search User & Business");

    MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener expandListener = new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {@Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Log.d(TAG, "On Menu Expand");
            //THIS METHOD NEVER CALLED
            //timeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Log.d(TAG, "On Menu Collapse");
            //THIS METHOD NEVER CALLED
            return true;
        }
    };
    item.setOnActionExpandListener(expandListener);
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item android:id="@+id/notificationBell"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menuitem_notification_count"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/search_PTL"
        android:title="Search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/places_ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView">
    </item>

</menu>
```

That's what i got from above code
[image]

I need to place time button inside searchview which is visible when searchview expand and hide when collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `SpannableStringBuilder`

**Code snippet with comments:**

```
    AutoCompleteTextView text = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);// get reference of textview of SearchView
    if (text != null) {

        SpannableStringBuilder magHint = new SpannableStringBuilder("  ");
        magHint.append("Search ...");//set text
        myDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), myDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());//myDrawable image you want to set
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(myDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        magHint.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//sets image span
        text.setHint(magHint);//set string for searchView hint
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. its showing inside search as per your code but its showing on left of search view. I want to show on end of the searchview.
And drawable doesn't provide setOnClickListner so how can set function on touch of image/drawable

Comment: But i don;t feel its optimal solution

Comment: @androidXP I think that's not posible. Only solution coming to my mind is somehow to reduce searchview width and set icon of clock in seperate toolbar element